# Locality is missing when search by postal code

Tags: geocode, zipcode, city

I am using the Google geocode API to search for a city when user input the postal code. This is the request: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=<my_key>&type=(regions)&language=de&address=2280:Austria

The expected result should be Glinzendorf but that is not what I am getting in response. Locality is not returned which I believe contains the city name.

I expected a result containing the correct locality = Glinzendorf.